# Rank categories in column based on sum of values in another column in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, hstack

Let's say there are 4 columns in Sheet 1 with col1 as categories and col2, col3, and col4 are value columns as shown below. In sheet 2, we want to obtain top 2 categories highest sum of values in the selected variable column.

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

I have used the following code to find top values for the table not for each categories, any suggestions to revise this?

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(INDEX(Sheet1!B2:D11,,MATCH(H1,Sheet1!B1:D1,0)),CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!A2:D11,1)),1,-1),5)
```

Desired output if VAR1 is in user input:

[image]

Note: The formulas should not be sensitive to column names in sheet1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Update as per present edited post by OP:**

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=HSTACK({1;2},
  TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!B2:D11,,XMATCH(H1,Sheet1!B1:D1)),
  Sheet1!A2:A11,Sheet1!A2:A11),Sheet1!A2:A11)),1,-1),2))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     a, Sheet1!A2:A11,
     HSTACK({1;2},TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(SUMIFS(
     XLOOKUP(H1,Sheet1!B1:D1,Sheet1!B2:D11),a,a),a)),1,-1),2))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     a, Sheet1!A2:A11,
     HSTACK({1;2},TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(
     SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!B2:D11,,XMATCH(H1,Sheet1!B1:D1)),a,a),a)),1,-1),2)))
```

---

> *Solutions shown below are referring to the original post of OP, which*
> *is a working solution. However, OP had special characters in header*
> *name on sheet1, which was not mentioned on the post.*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(A2:A12),
     b, TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(a,SUMIFS(B2:B12,A2:A12,a)),2,-1),2),
     VSTACK({"Rank","V1","V2"},HSTACK({1;2},b)))
```

---

You can also use the <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> in place of <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd>, <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> is more resource heavy than <kbd>SUMIFS</kbd>, so the latter will be simpler and more efficient, still shared the approach with <kbd>MMULT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(A2:A12),
     b, TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(a,MMULT(N(TOROW(A2:A12)=a),B2:B12)),2,-1),2),
     VSTACK({"Rank","V1","V2"},HSTACK({1;2},b)))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=HSTACK({1;2},
 TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A12,
 SUMIFS(B2:B12,A2:A12,A2:A12))),2,-1),2))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=HSTACK({"1";2},
 TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A12,
 MMULT(N(A2:A12=TOROW(A2:A12)),B2:B12))),2,-1),2))
```

---

**Edited :**

As mentioned by OP in comments below:

> *As shown in example can we take if the column to be considered for*
> *sorting as a user input as is given in cell E2 of desired output*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=HSTACK({1;2},
 TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A12, 
 SUMIFS(B2:B12,A2:A12,A2:A12))),
 XMATCH(D1,A1:B1),-1),2))
```

---

**Update:**

OP mentions in comments:

> *This code gives error if the data is in another sheet in the same*
> *workbook. The formula used example reads data from another sheet*

[image]

---

Excel can be downloaded from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckAyJctZMU6qyn_9x?e=pQWfaF)**

---

As per comments of OP:

> *The error occurs when column names have special characters like V2_AB*

[image]

---

```
=HSTACK({1;2},TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$12,
 SUMIFS(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$12,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$12,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$12))),
 XMATCH(E1,TEXTBEFORE(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1,"_",,,,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1)),-1),2))
```

---

Comment: As shown in example can we take if the column to be considered for sorting as a user input as is given in cell E2 of desired output

Comment: @vp_050 updated now, refer the last solution

Comment: This formula gives error

Comment: @vp_050 can you show me what error it gives you, you can clearly see my screenshot, it is working on my end. I have user input in cell `D1` which you might need to change, as you have in `E2`

Comment: @vp_050 let me know, so I can see and fix it, what issues you are facing in

Comment: This code gives error if the data is in another sheet in the same workbook. The formula used example reads data from another sheet

Comment: @vp_050 i really dont think it will give you any error, as i have found out it is clearly working on my end, and i have updated now it as well, attached workbook for your perusal.

Comment: The error occurs when column names have special characters like V2_AB

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya Every day I learn something. Clever using mmult.Thank you

Comment: @vp_050 just add the sheet name in front of the ranges? Sheet1![range_ref]

Comment: @P.b yes, I have already tried this

Comment: @vp_050 you are yet to reply on this